# Getting inline css value with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I get inline-css right value of second child of the div #one using jQuery.

```html
<li id="one">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, velit!</h2>
  <div style="width: 1425px; height: 1080px; right: 55px; top: 0px;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo dolorum reprehenderit natus consequuntur magnam exercitationem nemo similique labore laudantium iure libero at minus, aperiam sequi. Officiis rem optio, quasi perspiciatis facilis est. Aliquam quisquam atque ea earum odit, itaque, excepturi accusamus quasi neque voluptatibus ipsum error qui facilis magnam eveniet.</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Your div only has 1 child.

Comment: Oh, I'm trying to get the value of right: 55px from the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this documentation: http://api.jquery.com/css/
You can get inline css for 'right' like this:

```
$('div').css('right')
```

Or if you want to be more specific:

```
$('#one div').css('right')
```

if you want the first div:

```
$('#one div').first().css('right');

// you can also do this
$('#one div:first').css('right');
```

Comment: I need to reach the div through  parent ID, I have multiple divs with right attributes.

Comment: is the div you want to access always the first div inside the li ?

Comment: Is `#001` a valid CSS selector? It begins with a number.

Comment: Well strictly speaking I think an id attribute has to begin with [a-z] or [A-Z] for html 4. In html 5 this is valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#one div').css('right');
```

or

```
$('#one').find('div').css('right');
```

You can also add a class or and id for the div or access through a selector child with jquery.